# I want to select particular radio item in RadioListTile,

Tags: flutter, dart

> If i select the 1st index RadioListTile, then all 1st index in the expansion Tile is selected this is my problem, Here i want to select particular radio list and add the index to list

```
class Addon extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_AddonState createState() => _AddonState();
}  class _AddonState extends State<Addon> {
         List addonItem = ["Cool Drinks", "Extra Sauce"];
          int dummy;
      @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
     body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
        dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.down,
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: addonItem.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ExpansionTile(
            initiallyExpanded: false,
            title: Text(
              addonItem[index],
            ),
            children: [
              for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                RadioListTile(
                  value: i,
                  title: Text("item $i"),
                  groupValue: dummy,
                  activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    print(val);
                    setState(() {
                      dummy = val;
                    });
                  },
                )
            ],
          );
        }),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `int dummy;` as the selected value for both lists of buttons you can use two dummy values and add a condition to the rendering of the children of the `ExpansionTile` like this:

```
class Addon extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddonState createState() => _AddonState();
}

class _AddonState extends State<Addon> {
  List addonItem = ["Cool Drinks", "Extra Sauce"];
  int dummy1;
  int dummy2;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: addonItem.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ExpansionTile(
              initiallyExpanded: false,
              title: Text(
                addonItem[index],
              ),
              children: [
                if (addonItem[index] == 'Cool Drinks') 
                  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                  RadioListTile(
                    value: i,
                    title: Text("item $i"),
                    groupValue: dummy1,
                    activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      print(val);
                      setState(
                        () {
                          dummy1 = val;
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ), 
                if (addonItem[index] == 'Extra Sauce') 
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                  RadioListTile(
                    value: i,
                    title: Text("item $i"),
                    groupValue: dummy2,
                    activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      print(val);
                      setState(
                        () {
                          dummy2 = val;
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This checks if the value if the index you are accessing in `addonItem` and if the value is `'Cool Drinks'` you use one of the dummy values, if the index is `'Extra Sauce'` you use the other value, this makes sure you dont share the same value for both lists.

This only works if you are not adding values dynamically to the addonItem list.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But if i want to use "N" number of  addonItem  the code goes too long from your point of statement